# Crontab Ubuntu 16.04/PHP 7.0 cron job listed but PHP file not being run

Tags: bash, apache2, php, cron

When I enter `crontab -e` in the terminal I see my job listed to run every hour:

```
00 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/job.php
```

When I enter `crontab -l` I see the same job listed:

```
00 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/job.php
```

However the script doesn't run or execute. I have checked:

1. The script is in the proper file location and executes by itself with no errors
2. `/usr/bin/php` is where php is stored (`whereis php` returns `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/bin/php7.0`)
3. Have the exact same job running for root (`sudo crontab -l` lists the same job)
4. `cron` runs as a service (plus I restarted it)

What else could be the issue?

Comment: There should be corresponding entries in `/var/log/syslog` for when your script starts and ends. Example: `Apr  2 16:47:01 DOUG-64 CRON[18236]: (doug) CMD ([18237] /home/doug/test2/zzxxtest.sh)` and `Apr  2 16:47:01 DOUG-64 CRON[18236]: (doug) END ([18237] /home/doug/test2/zzxxtest.sh)`. When you exit `crontab -e` you should also have seen `crontab: installing new crontab`.

Comment: @DougSmythies I see in the log " CRON[17381]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronjobs/job.php)". Does this mean it ran?

Comment: It means the `root` one ran. You didn't see any entries for your user one? Then maybe try to stagger it in time from the `root` one.